# Disable double tap zoom in webbrowser windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, browser, zooming, pinchzoom

I am developing windows phone application.
I am using `WebBrowser` component of windows phone 8.I needed to disable zoom/pinch of browser.I am able to do this by using this [link](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html).
But when we **double tap** it does zoom little bit then again goes to original position.
How should I disable that also?

**Note**: I don't have control over HTML of web page.So no `Viewport` can be used.

**UPDATE**: I tried using `DoubleTap` event of border and webbrowser but events not getting called.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to interact with the html content or you want to display static content?

Comment: I am displaying web page content through url.